# Event listener "change" only works if focus is on object

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, jquery-events

I'm currently having a little struggle with this. The situation is the following. I have  multiple input fields on a page

Input1 and Input2 influence the content of Input3.

Now I wan't an event handler being triggered if content of Input3 changes. I tried:

```
$('#div-xy').on('change', 'input', function(){console.log('input changed')});
```

But that only seems to work if the focus is also on Input3 which isn't the case as I'm typing in input2 or input3.
I also tried:

```
$('#div-xy').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){console.log('CHANGE2')});
```

which sadly has the same effect. Do you maybe have an idea how to check for changes in Input3? Would appreciate the help.

Comment: Can you shared the code related to _Input1 and Input2 influence the content of Input3._

Comment: So if you don't want to attach listener to all `<input>` you clearly need to use a different selector than `input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change event only triggers on user input, but can be triggered explicitly.

Since you are using jQuery:

```
$('#input2').change(()=>{
    console.log('input 2 is changed');

    $('#input3').val('some val');
    $('#input3').change()
})

$('#input3').change(()=>{
    console.log('input 3 is changed');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

If you have many of these fields, rather than having a handler be bound to each one, you would get better performance by using a delegated event handler:

**HTML:**

```
<div id='parent'>
    <input type="text" class="search-field" />
    <input type="text" class="search-field" />
    <select class="search-field" ><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
    <input type="radio" class="search-field" />
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#parent').on('change', '.search-field', function() {
    // validate all search field values
    // display search results based on values
    // if search results already shown, filter based on $(this).val()
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: That's a pretty good approach. Unfortunately the structure of my page is pretty much fixed as it's a SharePoint-Site where I don't want to manipulate the DOM too much since this is likely to produce some problems further down the road.

Another thing is, that there can also be more than 2 inputs that influence the content of the third one and I found it to be a bit messy to aply the same event handler on all of them

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the change event occurs when the value of an element has been changed BY THE USER. It won't occur on it's own if the value of input3 is changed through jquery or some other code. However you can trigger that in any other jquery function manually and if there is a definition of input.change() then it will be executed.